# How to read Xcode's Instruments object relationship diagram?

Tags: ios, xcode, uml, instruments

During the process of finding the memory leaks in Xcode I am getting some diagrams but I cannot understand what do they mean.

- **Are they UML...?**
- **Where can I find information about them...?**

For an example, **what does this diagram mean...?** Some are red lines some are blue why?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: what does the Xcode RTFM manual say?

Comment: @Goppinath The best explanation I found was in one of Apple's WWDC video sessions about Instruments, either 2011 or 2012. I'm not sure of the exact year. The video covers the Cycles and Roots section of the Leaks instrument.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk, thanks I have already watched 2012 session and thats why I am really interested on Xcode's instruments. But now (after your comment) I found some more useful sessions from 2010 and 2011 let me watch it. Thanks again.